# Meaning of "shame someone into doing something"

Tags: meaning

The sentence "I tried to shame him into giving some away" is quoted from the New Oxford Dictionary.

What does "shame somebody into doing something" mean? As in this sentence:

> I tried to shame him into giving some away.

Maybe it means to make someone do something by shaming him/her?

Comment: See [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shame), sense 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Maybe it means to make someone do something by shaming him/her?

That's close. I'd say it means to make someone do something by making them feel shame if they **don't** do it.

Let's say I want you to give money to a charity. I may *entice* you to give ("If you give $50, they'll give you a free coffee mug!"), or I might *encourage* you to give ("This charity helps a lot of people; you should consider donating!"). I might also *badger* you to give, if I keep asking you day after day, "Have you given to that charity yet?"

However, if I were to *shame* you into giving, I would try to make you feel ashamed for NOT giving. For example, I might say:

> This charity gave you a lot of help when you were in need. Now that you've become wealthy, you're not going to help them out?

If that compelled you to give to the charity, then one might say that I *shamed* you into giving.